# Qt: Getting the elapsed time of a thread's member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv, time

I wish to grab a frame from a webcam at a specified maximum frame rate within a separate thread of execution using C++.

To do so, I am using OpenCV (for the webcam) and Qt (for the threading).

I have a thread `CameraThread` that is launched within the program's main thread that starts the camera and then continuously calls `CameraThread::getFrame()` via a while loop:

```
void CameraThread::getFrame(VideoCapture& cap)
{
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();

    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;

    // add frame to queue for processing
    image_queue->add(frame);

    int elapsed = timer.elapsed();

    int min_time = ceil(1000.0 / frame_rate); // min_time in ms, frame_rate in fps
    int time_left = min_time - elapsed;
    if (time_left > 0)
        msleep(time_left);

    cout << "elapsed=" << elapsed << "ms ";
    cout << "time_left=" << time_left << "ms" << endl;
}
```

However, if I set (for example) the `frame_rate` to 1 fps, then a typical output of the above function is:

```
elapsed=300ms time_left=700ms
elapsed=8ms time_left=992ms
elapsed=7ms time_left=993ms
elapsed=7ms time_left=993ms
elapsed=8ms time_left=992ms
elapsed=7ms time_left=993ms
elapsed=7ms time_left=993ms
... etc
```

The `QElapsedTimer` screws up after the first call to `CameraThread::getFrame()`.

What appears to be the culprit is the call to `msleep()`. When I remove this call, the `QElapsedTimer` seems to work as expected (~30ms, which corresponds the camera's default frame rate of 30 fps). However, I require the `CameraThread` to sleep for a specified period of time to ensure the maximum frame rate is adhered to.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: I don't see any problem. It just looks as if the first picture takes longer than all subsequent ones, which can easily be explained with caching effects. How often does the function output a line as in above quoted output? I'd expect one such line per second.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you should *never* call `msleep`, what's the actual problem? Have you tried digging into why the first frame takes longer? Maybe if you don't sleep you get stuck into `cap >> frame` waiting for the next frame, while if you sleep a frame is immediately ready, so reading+processing it takes a very short time?

Comment: (Apart from this: notice that `QElapsedTimer` has a 64-bit based API).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `msleep` you could create a QTimer outside if your method:

```
QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setInterval( ceil(1000.0 / frame_rate) );
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this](){
    getFrame(cap);
});
timer->start();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have no ideas what is the problem with QElapsedTimer, but may be you can use QTime? It has the same methods

```
void QTime::start();
int QTime::elapsed() const;
```

Comment: That's a very bad idea as `QTime` is not monotonic at all.

Comment: I tried this previously from a diagnostic standpoint, however it resulted in the same problem.